# Prove that $f^{-1}( \bigcap_j A_j) = \bigcap f^{-1}(A_j)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that $f^{-1}( \bigcap_j A_j) = \bigcap f^{-1}(A_j)$

$”\subset”$ Let $x \in f^{-1}( \bigcap_j A_j)$. This means that $f(x) \in \bigcap_j A_j$. Thus $f(x) \in A_j$ for every $j$. From here we have that $x \in f^{-1}(A_j)$ for every $j$, but this just means that $x \in \bigcap_j f^{-1}(A_j).$

$”\supset”$ Take $x \in \bigcap f^{-1}(A_j) $. Then $x \in f^{-1}(A_j)$ for every $j$. So $f(x) \in A_j$, for every $j$, but this means that $f(x) \in \bigcap_j A_j$ so $x \in f^{-1}(\bigcap_j A_j )$

Is my reasoning here correct? I’m not entirely sure about $”\supset”$?

Comment: Both inclusions are correct.

Comment: It's totally correct.

Comment: You don't need to handle the $\subset$ and $\supset$ parts separately, since the reasoning is the same in both directions.  So, using equivalences instead of implications, for all objects $x$, $x \in f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_j A_j\right)$ if and only if $x \in \bigcap_j f^{-1}(A_j)$; so (by the axiom of extension, if you're doing your set theory axiomatically) the result follows.